# Grouping the range of intervals based on 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a geologist needing to clean up data. 
I have a .csv file containing drilling intervals, that I imported as a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    hole_name   from    to  interval_type
0   A           0       1   Gold
1   A           1       2   Gold
2   A           2       4   Inferred_fault
3   A           4       6   NaN
4   A           6       7   NaN
5   A           7       8   NaN
6   A           8       9   Inferred_fault
7   A           9       10  NaN
8   A           10      11  Inferred_fault
9   B2          11      12  Inferred_fault
10  B2          12      13  Inferred_fault
11  B2          13      14  NaN
```

For each individual "hole_name", I would like to group/merge the "from" and "to" range for consecutive intervals associated with the same "interval_type". The NaN values can be dropped, they are of no use to me (but I already know how to do this, so it is fine).

Based on the example above, I would like to get something like this:

```
    hole_name   from    to  interval_type
0   A           0       2   Gold
2   A           2       4   Inferred_fault
3   A           4       8   NaN
6   A           8       9   Inferred_fault
7   A           9       10  NaN
8   A           10      11  Inferred_fault
9   B2          11      13  Inferred_fault
11  B2          13      14  NaN
```

I have looked around and tried to use groupby or pyranges but cannot figure how to do this...
Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

# create dataframe
data = {
    'hole_name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'from': [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
    'to': [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    'interval_type': ['Gold', 'Gold', 'Inferred_fault', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 
                      'Inferred_fault', np.nan, 'Inferred_fault', 'Inferred_fault', 
                      'Inferred_fault', np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# create auxiliar column that groups repetitive consecutive values
grouped = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(list(zip(df.hole_name.tolist(), df.interval_type.tolist())))]
df['interval_type_id'] = np.repeat(range(len(grouped)),[len(x) for x in grouped])+1

# aggregate results
cols = df.columns[:-1]
vals = []
for idx, group in df.groupby(['interval_type_id', 'hole_name']):
    vals.append([group['hole_name'].iloc[0], group['from'].min(), group['to'].max(), group['interval_type'].iloc[0]])

result = pd.DataFrame(data=vals, columns=cols)
result
```

`result` should be:

```
hole_name   from    to  interval_type
A   0   2   Gold
A   2   4   Inferred_fault
A   4   8   
A   8   9   Inferred_fault
A   9   10  
A   10  11  Inferred_fault
B   11  13  Inferred_fault
B   13  14
```

EDIT: added `hole_name` to the `groupby` function.

Comment: Thanks Carlos but it returns this error: "3 columns passed, passed data had 4 columns". And returns "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" if I add +1 to cols

Comment: in what row of the code above? I tried to make it as neat as possible to just copy paste and run

Comment: All good, I must have copy-pasted an early version of your code (I noticed some changes), it works like a charm now! Thank you so much Carlos!!

Answer (score 0):

You can first build an indicator column for grouping. Then use agg to merge the sub groups to get from and to.

```
(
    df.assign(ind=df.interval_type.fillna(''))
      .assign(ind=lambda x: x.ind.ne(x.ind.shift(1).bfill()).cumsum())
    .groupby(['hole_name', 'ind'])
    .agg({'from':'first', 'to':'last', 'interval_type': 'first'})
    .reset_index()
    .drop('ind',1)
)

hole_name   from    to  interval_type
0   A       0       2   Gold
1   A       2       4   Inferred_fault
2   A       4       8   NaN
3   A       8       9   Inferred_fault
4   A       9       10  NaN
5   A       10      11  Inferred_fault
6   B       11      13  Inferred_fault
7   B       13      14  NaN
```